# How to compute infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ne^{-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to compute the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ne^{-n}$.

I know the answer is $e/(e-1)^2$, but I don't understand how to find this result.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [This similar post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) should give you ideas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can differentiate the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$ to obtain $\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty n e^{-nx}$. Then just put $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approch:
$s=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx}$
So,$s=e^{-1}+2e^{-2}+...+$

Now if you consider $(s-e^{-1}s)$ you will get an infinite gp series. Then solving you can find $s.$