# Improper integral of exponential function times the integer part of $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, gre-exam

I would like to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} \lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x} dx$ for its exact solution. This was on a previous GRE Mathematics exam.

Comment: No, it's $\frac{1}{e-1}$

Comment: (And this is a definite integral)

Comment: Fixed, I meant improper I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the integral up into a sum of integrals over intervals of length 1. This way the floor of $x$ becomes constant for that interval. You get

$$\int_0^\infty = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\left(\int_k^{k+1}e^{-x}dx\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\left(-e^{-(k+1)} + e^{-k}\right)$$

Breaking up this sum into two we get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\left(-e^{-(k+1)} + e^{-k}\right) = -\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}(l-1)e^{-l} + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}me^{-m}$$

Since the first term of the second sum is clearly zero, we can start the summation from 1 instead of zero to get

$$-\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}(l-1)e^{-l} + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}me^{-m} = -\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}(l-1)e^{-l} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}me^{-m}$$

Now we're able to combine these back into one sum to get

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( (1-n)e^{-n} + ne^{-n} \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n},$$

which is a power series. This finally gives us

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-n} - e = \frac{1}{1- 1/e} - e = \frac{e}{1- 1/e}= \frac{1}{e- 1}$$

---

I'm sure there's a shorter way of doing this whole thing but I'm not thinking very clearly right now.

Comment: How do you get the equality when you break up the sums? I see that the second sum corresponds to the first term in the parenthesis, but what about the first sum. How come $ke^{-(k+1)}=(k-1)e^{-k}$?

Comment: @DanZimm Yes, I just noticed that. Fixing.

Comment: The right answer should be $\frac{1}{e-1}$. I'm attempting to fix the error.

Comment: @AdamStaples Fixed one error, still wrong though.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com/a/525040/99024 This gives a possible way of computing the sum above. Man being this clever on a GRE timed Math exam is difficult for sure.

Comment: @AdamStaples Wolfram Alpha [agrees with your answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28+k*+%28-exp%28-%28k%2B1%29%29+%2B+exp%28-k%29+%29+%29%2C+0+to+infinity)

Comment: @AdamStaples I'm starting to study for the exam too, I feel the same way >.<

Comment: Basically Once you have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ne^{-n}$, we're done. This can be done by realizing $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ne^{-nx}$  is the derivative of 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$. Integrating both sides and then plugging in x = 1 gives the desired result.

Comment: @AdamStaples Got it. Power series was starting summation at 1, not 0. All correct now.

Answer (score 9):

Your integral is equal to $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{\int_n^{n+1}{ne^{-x}dx}}$

You can simplify from here.

Comment: Then $\left.\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -ne^{-x}\right|_n^{n+1}$ = 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ne^{-n} (1-\frac{1}{e})$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/525040/99024
This gives a possible way of computing the sum above.