# Is this series computable?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to compute the value of this series:

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n = 0}^{+ \infty} n . e^{- \alpha n}
\end{equation*}

Where $\alpha$ is a constant.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) may give you some ideas.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the related links: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525021/how-to-compute-infinite-series-sum-n-0-infty-ne-n?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n = 0}^{ \infty} n  e^{- a n}
$
 can be written
$\sum_{n = 0}^{ \infty} n  (e^{- a})^ n
=\sum_{n = 0}^{ \infty} n  x^ n
$
where
$x = e^{-a}
$.

This is a well-known sum
that is asked here often.

Ways of evaluating this
include
differentiating
$\sum_{n = 0}^{ \infty}   x^ n
$
and multiplying the sum
by $1-x$.

Have at it.